# Calculate pixelwise distance of 3D tensor in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, heatmap, euclidean-distance

I am trying to create a 3d distance map (size: W * H * D) in tensorflow to be used in a loss function for training. I have a ground truth (binary volume of size W * H * D) that I will use to create the distance map, i.e. the value of each pixel of my distance map will be the minimum distance of that pixel to the positive valued (i.e pixel=1) shape in the ground truth.
Having issues with the 3d shape problem as L2.NORM reduce the axis to a 2D shape and making this problem fully differentiable.  Any advice or pointers would be much appreciated.

[image: Slice screenshot of the ground truth mask]

Comment: Can you please give an example of exactly what you need? And if possible the kind of thing you have tried? I'm not sure I understand the inputs and outputs of the problem. Is the ground truth a 3D binary tensor (just made up of ones and zeros), or something else? And you want to compute, for a volume the same size, the distance to the closest 1 in the ground truth?

Comment: @jdehesa Sure, I have a 3d volume shape (112,112,112) thats the ground truth mask Structure 1 = 1, Structure2=2, background = 0. 
I get the ground truth mask and take only structure 2 (threshold) I then inverse this (i.e. background =1 and foreground =0 now). I now try to generate a euclidean distance transform as in scipy.ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_edt in tensorflow. TF have a 2D case of this but hard to translate to 3D. What I want is a 3D tensor with high values at positions very far from pixel value 0 and lower values at positions closer to pixel value 0 for a new loss fn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to compute the distance from each position in the volume to the closest position of a given class. For simplicity, I will assume that the interesting class is labelled with `1`, but hopefully you can adapt it to your case if it is different. The code is for TensorFlow 2.0, but should work the same for 1.x.

The simplest way to do this is to compute the distance between all the coordinates in the volume against every coordinate with a `1`, and then pick the smallest distance from there. You can do that like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Make input data
w, h, d = 10, 20, 30
w, h, d = 2, 3, 4
t = tf.random.stateless_uniform([w, h, d], (0, 0), 0, 2, tf.int32)
print(t.numpy())
# [[[0 1 0 0]
#   [0 0 0 0]
#   [1 1 0 1]]
#
#  [[1 0 0 0]
#   [0 0 0 0]
#   [1 1 0 0]]]
# Make coordinates
coords = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(w), tf.range(h), tf.range(d), indexing='ij')
coords = tf.stack(coords, axis=-1)
# Find coordinates that are positive
m = t > 0
coords_pos = tf.boolean_mask(coords, m)
# Find every pairwise distance
vec_d = tf.reshape(coords, [-1, 1, 3]) - coords_pos
# You may choose a difference precision type here
dists = tf.linalg.norm(tf.dtypes.cast(vec_d, tf.float32), axis=-1)
# Find minimum distances
min_dists = tf.reduce_min(dists, axis=-1)
# Reshape
out = tf.reshape(min_dists, [w, h, d])
print(out.numpy().round(3))
# [[[1.    0.    1.    2.   ]
#   [1.    1.    1.414 1.   ]
#   [0.    0.    1.    0.   ]]
#
#  [[0.    1.    1.414 2.236]
#   [1.    1.    1.414 1.414]
#   [0.    0.    1.    1.   ]]]
```

This may work well enough for you, although it may not be the most efficient solution. The smartest thing would be to search for the closest positive position in the neighboring area of each position, but that is complicated to do effectively, both in general and more so in a vectorized way in TensorFlow. There are however a couple of ways we can improve on the code above. On the one hand, we know that positions with a `1` will always have zero distance, so computing for those is unnecessary. On the other hand, if the `1` class in the 3D volume represents some kind of dense shape, then we could save some time if we only computed the distances against the surface of that shape. All other positive positions will have necessarily a greater distance to positions outside the shape. So we can do the same thing we were doing, but computing only distances from non-positive positions to positive surface positions. You can do that like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Make input data
w, h, d = 10, 20, 30
w, h, d = 2, 3, 4
t = tf.dtypes.cast(tf.random.stateless_uniform([w, h, d], (0, 0)) > .15, tf.int32)
print(t.numpy())
# [[[1 1 1 1]
#   [1 1 1 1]
#   [1 1 0 0]]
# 
#  [[1 1 1 1]
#   [1 1 1 1]
#   [1 1 1 1]]]
# Find coordinates that are positive and on the surface
# (surrounded but at least one 0)
t_pad_z = tf.pad(t, [(1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1)]) <= 0
m_pos = t > 0
m_surround_z = tf.zeros_like(m_pos)
# Go through the 6 surrounding positions
for i in range(3):
    for s in [slice(None, -2), slice(2, None)]:
        slices = tuple(slice(1, -1) if i != j else s for j in range(3))
        m_surround_z |= t_pad_z.__getitem__(slices)
# Surface points are positive points surrounded by some zero
m_surf = m_pos & m_surround_z
coords_surf = tf.where(m_surf)
# Find coordinates that are zero
coords_z = tf.where(~m_pos)
# Find every pairwise distance
vec_d = tf.reshape(coords_z, [-1, 1, 3]) - coords_surf
dists = tf.linalg.norm(tf.dtypes.cast(vec_d, tf.float32), axis=-1)
# Find minimum distances
min_dists = tf.reduce_min(dists, axis=-1)
# Put minimum distances in output array
out = tf.scatter_nd(coords_z, min_dists, [w, h, d])
print(out.numpy().round(3))
# [[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
#   [0. 0. 0. 0.]
#   [0. 0. 1. 1.]]
#
#  [[0. 0. 0. 0.]
#   [0. 0. 0. 0.]
#   [0. 0. 0. 0.]]]
```

EDIT: Here is one way in which you can divide the distance computations in chunks with a TensorFlow loop:

```py
# Following from before
coords_surf = ...
coords_z = ...
CHUNK_SIZE = 1_000 # Choose chunk size
dtype = tf.float32
# If using TF 2.x you can know in advance the size of the tensor array
# (although the element shape will not be constant due to the last chunk)
num_z = tf.shape(coords_z)[0]
arr = tf.TensorArray(dtype, size=(num_z - 1) // CHUNK_SIZE + 1, element_shape=[None], infer_shape=False)
_, arr = tf.while_loop(lambda i, arr: i < num_z,
                       lambda i, arr: (i + CHUNK_SIZE, arr.write(i // CHUNK_SIZE,
                           tf.reduce_min(tf.linalg.norm(tf.dtypes.cast(
                               tf.reshape(coords_z[i:i + CHUNK_SIZE], [-1, 1, 3]) - coords_surf,
                           dtype), axis=-1), axis=-1))),
                       [tf.constant(0, tf.int32), arr])
min_dists = arr.concat()
out = tf.scatter_nd(coords_z, min_dists, [w, h, d])
```

Comment: I'm actually not sure if, for the second snippet, I need to check for surrounding zeros in 26 ways (with diagonals) or just 6 ways (without diagonals).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help it looks great and I really appreciate it, I will try to implement it today/tomorrow. The structure is quite central but small so I think the the 26 ways would ensure that the boundary is found? I have attached a snapshot of the structure in the original question.

Comment: @HelenaWilliams Yes, I think that 26 ways should work, I was wondering if checking for zeros just 6 ways (which would yield fewer surface points, hence requiring fewer operations later) would be okay, that is, if there is any case where a white pixel with black pixels on the diagonals (but not in 6-way neighborhood) may be the closest white pixel for some black pixel (in which case checking only for 6-way would be wrong, because I wouldn't be counting that white pixel as "surface").

Comment: my only issue so far is that my input tensor is of shape (300,400,500) (will be (112,112,112) due to sampling during training), but its still a very large tensor. So when I do the boolean mask/stack function most functions I get  a resource memory error. I am now trying if i can use the tf.where() function to just get position of the pixels instead but then I can no longer reshape to w h d .

Comment: @HelenaWilliams You're right, `tf.where` is the correct function here. Also 1) I had an error where `coords_z` was defined with `~m_surf` instead of `~m_pos`, resulting in correct result but more computation 2) Thinking more about it, I'm pretty sure 6-way neighbor check is fine, which should also reduce the computation. I updated the code accordingly (neighbor check is a bit uglier now). Still, it is very possible that this still takes too much memory, particularly `vec_d` and `dists`. One possibility is to make the computation in chunks with a `tf.while_loop`, although it's kind of a pain.

Comment: @HelenaWilliams I added one possible way to divide the distance computation with a loop (note each "chunk" would be compared to every point in the surface, if there are many surface points you may need to use small chunks, if there are not that many you can increase the size). At heart, the algorithm is still quite brute-force, I'm not sure whether it might be feasible to implement a smarter geometrical algorithm in TensorFlow more effectively...

Comment: thanks very much for the help,  I will try implement it with my nii.gz ground truth volume. Yes I am not sure, I was hoping to create a distance map on every iteration as a distance cost function so this may be too computationally expensive. Perhaps some general contour map  from a central point of the ground truth would suffice- but then you would loose the shape of the structure and it would generalise to a sphere?